# TSC build failed due to issue in google-cloud package,

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

**After upgrading to the latest version of Firebase-admin (8.0.0) cannot build firebase functions written in TypeScript**

The errors are for example:

- Property 'getMetadata' in type 'Notification' is not assignable to
  the same property in base type 'ServiceObject
- Property 'get' in type 'Notification' is not assignable to the same
  property in base type 'ServiceObject'.
- Property 'request' in type 'Bucket' is not assignable to the same
  property in base type 'ServiceObject'.

try to downgrade to firebase-admin 7.4.0 - did not solve

Package.json:
"firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
"firebase-firestore-timestamp": "^1.0.4",
"firebase-functions": "^3.1.0",

Comment: What is your TypeScript version?

Comment: I am having the same issue with typescript version 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to run

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/storage
```

in the **functions** directory.

I had this issue after updating gcloud. Seemingly, this module was then outdated and just needed an upgrade.